# Fabric8 CRD-Generator - is it possible to generate CRD yaml with x-kubernetes-validations?

Tags: fabric8, kubernetes-custom-resources, fabric8-kubernetes-client

The CRD-Generator provided by the Fabric8 kubernetes-client allows you to generate the CRD yaml from Java classes. The [documentation](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/main/doc/CRD-generator.md) shows a number of annotations that can be applied to fields in the spec, but I'm interested in being able to define more complex validation rules leveraging the [x-kubernetes-validations extension](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#validation-rules).

Is there a way to define these in the Java classes of the spec and have them produced in the CRD yaml?

Comment: As of today, `x-kubernetes-validations` is not supported by the CRD generator.
The various ways out of this are:
- contribute its support
- switch to a different approach (e.g. contract first leveraging the Java generator instead)
- inject the necessary yaml with a "post-processor" before shipping the CRDs

Comment: thanks @andreaTP , for the post-processor idea, is there a standard way to do that? or some kind of custom build step that would take a separate yaml with the validations and inject it into the CRD yaml generated from the build?

Comment: I'd also be quite interested in this. I feel like there must be a way to inject this field using Jackson-magic, but I couldn't quite get it to work yet. Using a post-processor splits up the CRD specification and its validation logic, which I feel belong very closely together – ideally in the same class

Comment: Sorry for the delay, there is, currently, no "generic way" to inject custom fields nor guidelines for post-processors unfortunately.

Some time ago I opened this Issue: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/3768 but it went down in priority due to the lack of people requesting it.

Comment: Update, support for validation rules is landing in the Fabric8 Kubernetes Client: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/pull/5788